# How to open an existing record in edit mode in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am not able to open an existing record in edit mode. This is the return of the Python method which opens the form view of the record:

```
@api.multi
def open_view(self):
    return {
        'name': _('My Wizard'),
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'my.model',
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': self.id,
    }
```

And I have tried (with no success) to add to the return dictionary the following keys:

**Flag option `mode`**

```
'flags': {
    'form': {
        'options': {
            'mode': 'edit',
        },
    }
},
```

*It does nothing, I guess it only works if the key `res_id` is missing.*

**Flag option `initial_mode`**

```
'flags': {
    'form': {
        'options': {
            'initial_mode': 'edit',
        },
    }
},
```

*Same as `mode`.*

**Context keys `form_view_initial_mode` and `force_detailed_view`**

```
'context': {
    'form_view_initial_mode': 'edit',
    'force_detailed_view': 'true'
},
```

*They do nothing either, they seem to work only in version 11.*

**Target `inline`**

```
'target': 'inline',
```

*This is the only one which works, but it makes dissapear Create and Edit buttons from the top of the form, and I do not want that.*

In conclusion, I need to open an **existing record** in edit mode and with `'target': 'current'` to have common form buttons and be like a normal form (not a pop-up).

Does anyone know how to manage this?

Answer (score 3):

with odoo v12

```
return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'project.project',
        'res_id': MY_RECORD.id,
        'context': {'form_view_initial_mode': 'edit'},
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`'flags': {'initial_mode': 'edit'}` should work in Odoo V10.

I tried it with a server action on `hr.employee` with the folling code. I added the action to the more/action menu, opened an employee in form view and started the action.

```py
action ={
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'hr.employee',
        'target': 'current',
        'res_id': record.id,
        'flags': {'initial_mode': 'edit'}
    }
```

Comment: I'm not able to make it work, for me it only works if I remove the key `res_id` from the return dictionary, but I cannot do that because I need to open a specific record. May be it is not working because the record is an instance of a Transient Model? I don't think this should affect the common behaviour.

Comment: i've edited my answer with my tested example. I've used `res_id`, too.